# Azure: Multiple FTP Sites

Tags: azure, ftp, dns

I've made an FTP site through IIS using the DNS Name I was given when I signed up, but I want to set up multiple FTP sites on the same virtual server. How can I do this?

Also, the one FTP site I set up can't be connected to through anything other than an FTP client - I can't connect via IE / Chrome or Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no multiple FTP account support for Azure App Service (formerly known as Azure Websites)

I am able to use IE to FTP to my site. what error do you see? Make sure you enter your credential and not login as anonymous user.

[image]

Comment: Ah, that's a nuisance. Thanks for the info Xiaomin!

hmmm, so if I wanted to have an FTP site with 2 folders, some users can access folder 1, but not folder 2... and some users can access folder 2 but not folder 1... How can I do that with Azure? can that be done with IIS FTP in one FTP site?

The error I get accessing my FTP site without an FTP client is:

An error occurred while opening that folder on the FTP server. Make sure that you have permission to access that folder.

Details:
200 Type set to A.
227 Entering Passive Mode (100,72,80,119,33)

I get this even when I use anonymous access

Comment: @Lewyh Please don't ask additional questions in comments. This is not a discussion forum. Ask a separate question.